# Access public method vs public constant Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and I am still trying to understand the basics. For this I couldn't find information in the Internet. Imagine this example:

```
class Person

  AGE = 18
  def self.get_age
    18
  end

end
```

From the console:

> Person.get_age

`=> 18`

> Person.AGE

`=> NoMethodError: undefined method AGE' for Person:Class`

Why this difference in the syntax?

Trying `Person::AGE` and `Person::get_age`, both yield the same:

`=> 18` 
As I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is different because you can do this :

```rb
class Person
  AGE = 18
  def self.AGE
    19
  end
end
```

`Person::AGE` will return 18 because you're accessing a constant.
`Person.AGE` will return 19 because you're accessing a method.

Basically, `::` is the constant separator while `.` is the method calling separator (when the following word starts with a capital letter and there's no parenthesis in the expression).

Comment: ":: is the constant separator while . is the method calling separator."  - Not quite. You can call methods with `::`. `Person::new`, `user::persisted?`, etc.

Comment: True but confusing since you have to make sure the method doesn't starts with a capital letter otherwise you need to use parenthesis to make sure it'll call the method. I'd prefer always following this rubocop rule : https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/ColonMethodCall (I'll try to rephrase my assertion).

Comment: Adding to @SergioTulentsev `::` is a namespace resolution operator. It helps you to access items in modules, or class-level items in classes or Constants. it is used to provide namespaces so that method and class names don't conflict with other classes.